# Как закреплять знания в PHP?

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток. Учу PHP. Скажите, пожалуйста, как можно закреплять свои знания. Спасибо.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по PHP](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/458485/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-php)

Answer (score 2):

Пишите странички с использованием знаний. Причем желательно брать примеры сложнее тех, которые есть в книгах etc: начали учить графику - поставьте задачу нарисовать светящийся кубик, регулярки - попробуйте вытащить все переменные (в т.ч. свойства объектов) в куске кода, кодировки - пишите функцию автоматической конвертации, сокеты - пишите свой sendmail, ну и т.д. Таким образом конкретно то, что вы учите, отложится чуть не в моторике, ну и заодно можно на какое-то нетривиальное использование нарваться.

Answer (score 1):

Теория без практики мертва. Поставьте перед собой задачу - реализовать какой-нибудь полноценный проект. В ходе работы Вы не только закрепите полученные знания, но и непременно почерпнете для себя много нового.

Answer (score 0):

Не обязательно, писать проект с 0 можно взять какой нибуть готовый движок, дополняя его все возможными модулями привидите его к наилучшему варианту. Это проверенный способ за полгода знакомства с движком чата Д. Бородина начал свободно писать на РНР.

Answer (score 0):

Скажу с чего я начинал. Беру учебник php и MySQl (Библия пользователя) и опираясь на нее делаю какой либо фрагмент. Например - регистрация сайта. Авторизация и тд. Немного завязнешь сразу, но потом легче станет. А просто смотреть в учебник - толку мало. Только если применять знания. не тупо коды перепечатывать, а именно самому придумывать алгоритмы и осуществлять - а учебник что то вроде справочника по функциям и синтаксису.