# Изучение языка программирования PHP

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Я тут решил изучить язык программирования PHP. И хотел задать такой вопрос: с чего лучше начать? Какие книги прочитать? И как его более эффективно освоить? Скиньте ссылки, если есть возможность. Всем заранее спасибо =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обратите внимание на вопросы:

- [С чего начать новичку в изучении PHP?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/24849/%D1%81-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-php)
- [Как закреплять знания в PHP?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/19995/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-php)

Answer (score 0):

С чтения [документации](http://www.php.su/) и изучения [форума](http://www.php.ru/forum/)

Answer (score 0):

Я начинал с самого сложного. С ООП. Причем не зная ничего про PHP. Так я прогал когда-то на С, мне несложно было. Я это сделал потому, что когда прогал на С, мне сложно было с линейного программирования перейти на ООП. Долго разбирался с объектами итд.